Creating singletons of derived class from a base class
Hi i have a bunch of managers which are all singletons for each type that they manage, but i am wondering if i can reduce the annoyance having to setup the singleton logic in each derived class because its rather repetitive code.
I could not do it in the base class because i could not create new T() in the Instance property, so resorted to doing it in the derived classes. I am wondering how it can be done if at all besides my current repetitive way:
public abstract class EntityManager<T>
{
    protected List<T> _entities;
    public IReadOnlyList<T> Entities => _entities;
}
public sealed class BuildingManager : EntityManager<Building>
{
    //repetitive code
    static readonly BuildingManager _instance;
    public static BuildingManager Instance => _instance ?? new();
}
public sealed class WallManager : EntityManager<Wall>
{
    //reptitive code
    static readonly WallManager _instance;
    public static WallManager Instance => _instance ?? new();
}

For every new type i have to write the same two lines of code, which makes me think there must be a better way to do it to make it cleaner.
Is there a better way ?

You can add a new() constraint to generics with where T: new() which will allow you to instantiate them assuming they possess a parameterless constructor. But really, I think the problem is more of a design or architecture issue. Why do you need so many singletons? Why do you need singletons at all? Generally managing instances and instance lifetimes is handled via some sort of DI provider these days rather than polluting your application with global state.

Well the managers contain all the objects created for a level in my game. I don't want more than one manager per type, they act as systems for the entities. I don't really see much benefit of creating instances here. Saves me passing around references all over the places then.

That's what DI containers are for; they handle constructing objects with appropriate references resolved. Also, if it matters... I don't believe your singleton implementation is thread-safe.

@WDUK - You know that since _instance is null then every single time you call .Instance you're getting a new instance? It's not a singleton at all.

When I need to "track" objects, I use a static collection and a static "factory" method; instead of calling the constructor directly. No "extra code" from the client side; the maintance, and tracking, is done by the "factory". The factory can also manage lifetimes: deleting stale entries automatically with each update. The factory (repository) also has statics for getting the "most" of something (nearest; deadliest) it is tracking.

The best you're going to get is using a property with an initial value.
public sealed class BuildingManager : EntityManager<Building>
{
    public static BuildingManager Instance { get; private set; } = new BuildingManager();
}

public sealed class WallManager : EntityManager<Wall>
{
    public static WallManager Instance { get; private set; } = new WallManager();
}



For every new type i have to write the same two lines of code, which
makes me think there must be a better way to do it to make it cleaner.

Actually, three lines if you want to have a classic Singleton. The third being:
private BuildingManager() { }

otherwise nothing prevents some code from calling the default public constructor, i.e. new().
So, if we have to have the private constructor, this also means that the only place we can instantiate our single instance is from within the class code and we have to have the static T Instance there too.
Based on your comment:

I don't want more than one manager per type, they act as systems for
the entities.

the current setup even if correctly implemented is not guaranteeing that either because we can declare another singleton say:
AnotherBuildingManager : EntityManager<Building>

Now, which of the two singletons is going to be the one manager for the Building type? You can't really prevent a second class from inheriting from EntityManager<Building>.
Maybe you could implement a static Dictionary that resolves from T (e.g. Bulding) to the correct EntityManager<Building> (e.g. BuildingManager). But then you still have the classic singleton API and you can always get instances in the wrong way via the static T Instance property (e.g. AnotherBuildingManager.Instance still gives us an EntityManager<Building> instance even when we decided to use BuildingManager)...
So for your use case, as lots of other people suggested, using DI Containers would make the most sense, since they have been developed to help with configuration scenarios like yours (especially for using generic classes like you do)
